# What is the topology of $E^*(E)$ where $E$ is a ring spectrum?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

In Adams' [lectures on generalised cohomology](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0081960#page-1) Page 51, it states $E^*(E)$ is a topology ring. I do not know the topology on it. the reference that Adams offered there is by Novikov in Russian. Can anyone help to explain it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have spectra $X$ and $Y$.  For any finite spectrum $W$, and any maps $X\xleftarrow{i}W\xrightarrow{f}Y$, we define 
$$ N(i,f) = \{g\colon X\to Y \;|\; gi=f\} \subseteq [X,Y]. $$
Sets of this type form a basis for a topology on the set $[X,Y]$.  If $X$ is a CW spectrum (as it always is in Adams's book) then you can restrict attention to the case where $W$ is a finite subspectrum of $X$ and $i$ is the inclusion; this will give the same topology.  Note that when $X$ itself is finite the topology is discrete, so the definition is only really interesting in the infinite case.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope you do not mind me asking a few quesitons about it. 1 Do I need to module the homotopy equivalence in [X,Y]? If so, is it obvious to see the definition of N(i,f) is compatible with the quotient. 2 Can I think this one as an analogue to the open compact topology for mapping space? 3 Why this topology is important in the infinite case?(I need to consider it when using Adams Novikov Spectral Sequence in cohomology)? Thanks again!